# How can I read a text file in Android?

Tags: java, android, exception, inputstream

I want to read the text from a text file.  In the code below, an exception occurs (that means it goes to the `catch` block).  I put the text file in the application folder.  Where should I put this text file (mani.txt) in order to read it correctly?

```
    try
    {
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("E:\\test\\src\\com\\test\\mani.txt"); 
        if (instream != null)
        {
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream); 
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader); 
            String line,line1 = "";
            try
            {
                while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null)
                    line1+=line;
            }catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        String error="";
        error=e.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: what do you hope your emulator is a part of your s/m? "E:\\test\\src\\com\\test\\mani.txt"

Comment: from which location you want to read text file... ?

Comment: InputStream  iS = resources.getAssets().open(fileName); ( if you put the file in assets)

Comment: @Sandip actually i copied text file (mani.txt) and put it into the folder of android application(folder having .settings , bin,libs,src,assets,gen,res,androidmanifeast.xml)

Comment: @user1635224 : put this file in asset folder. and refer following code... If you face any problem then ask directly

Comment: or put in simply res/raw folder and check my updated answer.

Comment: @Sandip : thank u very much, i put in asset folder and i got result

Answer (score 8):

Try this code

```
public static String pathRoot = "/sdcard/system/temp/";
public static String readFromFile(Context contect, String nameFile) {
    String aBuffer = "";
    try {
        File myFile = new File(pathRoot + nameFile);
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
        String aDataRow = "";
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            aBuffer += aDataRow;
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Shortest form for small text files (in Kotlin):

```
val reader = FileReader(path)
val txt = reader.readText()
reader.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      String line="";
      String s ="";
   try 
   {
       line = reader.readLine();
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
      while (line != null) 
      {
       s = s + line;
       s =s+"\n";
       try 
       {
           line = reader.readLine();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    tv.setText(""+s);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
    //todo when permission is granted
 } else {
    //request for the permission
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
```

// Add in Maifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```