# Read From txt file in android in mobile device

Tags: android, filereader

I have some several txt file already.I want to read this files in my application.i click button and choose name of txt file and read it. How i do it?
pls help me.

Comment: This question may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-to-read-text-file-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the file in the asset directory of the projet and use

```
      AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
```

I think this link can help you : http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code listing to read contents of a text file.

To get the path:

```
File file = app.getFilesDir();
String path = file.getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath() + "<filename.extension>";

--------------------------------------------------------

public static String readAllContents(String path) {

    String fileContents = null;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            fileContents = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("exception", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("exception", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return fileContents;
}
```