# How to display data from local file?

Tags: android, json, android-activity, offline-caching

[how to fetch data from local json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994878/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file)

Using this I fetch data from local json file. But I want to display every details which are present in json file which is stored in internal memory have to diaplay in list view. I tried to pass every data as string and use it. But It is not working.

Please provide some other solution to do this.

Comment: @andruboy thanks for ur reply.Image name, title, description what every it is in json file.

Comment: can you post JSON code? and also code that you print in listview

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ I follow this tutorial to do this.

Comment: you have fatch data from JSON file and created JSON object Right ?

Comment: I can fetch data.. so I have to parse json into java object or json object then only i can able to display data.. Am I right?

Comment: yes first you have to read file and create JSONObject and from JSONObject you can settext like textview.setText(jsonObject.optString("title"));

Comment: thanks.. I'll try this. If possible plz provide any sample to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

you have ask for Example so here

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data)//data will from your file 

TextView tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewtTitle);
tvTitle.setText(jsonObject.optString("title);
```