# Unable to read .txt file which stored on local storage

Tags: android, android-file

I am trying to read **`file.txt`** file which stored on my SD Card but am unable read it on my app. I provided

> `"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

permissions on manifest. Not sure where it went wrong. Please see my code below what i tried.

> ```
> //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
>      //*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
>      File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
>
>      //Get the text file
>       File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");
>
>      //Read text from file
>       StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
>
>       try {
>        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
>       String line;
>
>        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
>         text.append(line);
>         text.append('\n');
>     }
>     br.close();
>      }
>       catch (IOException e) {
>        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
>     }
>
>     //Find the view by its id
>      TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
>
>     //Set the text
>      tv.setText(text);
> ```

Comment: try to print the logs in `catch (IOException e) {`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)

Comment: yes SRB bans,i tried.but i did not get any thing.my screen showing nothing

Comment: yaa Rucha Bhatt. i get this code from there but when i am trying in my android phone its showing nothing.please help me.

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: and one more thing please make sure the file you are reading is not empty

Comment: Improved formate