# Android cat command returns empty

Tags: java, android, shell

I have problem with run getRuntime().exec() with cat command. 
The code returns empty result.
The code is here

```
try {

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" cat /data/.num");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();

        // Waits for the command to finish.
        process.waitFor();

        sharedPref.edit().putString("NUMBER",output.toString()).apply();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

but when I run this command from terminal (adb shell) it returns correct result

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but why are you using `cat` to read the content of a file?

Comment: What do you suggest instance of cat?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377185/133203)

Comment: reading that path requires root access. Do you have it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes have the root access, it is possible read from shell