# Handling shared text file in Android Apps?

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anyone explain how can I handle a shared .txt file in my android app?

I want to handle .txt files which are shared using ACTION_SEND or ACTION_VIEW intent.

Comment: well this looks pretty convincing to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? What specifically do you need help with? See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters and https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters for more.