# How to get data of a particular file in android/flutter?

Tags: file, flutter, compression

Recently I have started doing some research on file compression and other file handling topics. I got a basic idea about those like how file compression actually work and all. But I don't know how to get the data of a file so that it can be compressed.

How can I get the data of a video or an image file, or an application so that I can compress it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read a text file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)

Comment: Buffered Reader is used for text file to get the data from it ............ But what about other types of files ?

Comment: It's the same as reading from any other file.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for answering man, it is really helpful .... I'll look into it .