# java.io.filenotfoundexception: open failed: enoent (no such file or directory). Opening file from directory res

Tags: java, android

I need to get text from files in directory Tasks. Every file has name "tasks" + class (1 or 2) + random symbol from specifications[]
I tried to open file in

```
\\app\\src\\main\\res\\Tasks\\
```

and I can't do this. Below is my code.

```
public class Task1 extends AppCompatActivity {
final Random random = new Random();
public String specifications[] = new String\[\]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
"8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" , "f"};
public String[] linii = new String[5];
public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
int clasik = arguments.getInt("class") - 2131230843;
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\Project\\Proektorat\\app\\src\\main\\res\\Tasks\\tasks" + clasik + specifications[random.nextInt(15)] + ".txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
int i = 0;
while ((br.readLine()) != null){
linii[i] += br.readLine();
i += 1;
}
```

And errors:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\\Project\\Proektorat\\app\\src\\main\\res\\Tasks\\tasks1a.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.\<init\>(FileInputStream.java:160)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.\<init\>(FileInputStream.java:115)
W/System.err:     at com.example.project.Task1.main(Task1.java:26)
W/System.err:     at com.example.project.Task1.onCreate(Task1.java:41)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269)
```

Comment: are you running your app in emulator??

Comment: An Android app running on your Android device and you are not at home has no access to files on your pc. D:\... is a path on your pc.

Comment: If you were at home with your phone you would not have access too ;-)

Comment: yes, i am running it on API 33

Comment: @blackapps So, what path should I use then?

Comment: Files in res/Tasks are resources at runtime for your app. There is no file parh then. Use the resource manager. Something with getResources() or do. Maybe the Tasks directory is not possible. For a start put them directly in res/raw.

Comment: So, I did - sadly, but nothing changed. The error is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing your computers resources, which is inaccessible from your phone/emulator.

Take a look at [this introduction](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) on how to work with resources. Especially the part [Accessing original files](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#OriginalFiles) might be of interest for you.

Alternatively you can use the phone's/emulator's [file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android) and upload a file with [device file explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) (it's a Linux system, just in case you aren't familiar with)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your suggestion to use emulator's file system worked!